# Inserting <select> button into HTML table using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, innerhtml

I am attempting to insert an input button into an HTML table using  .innerHTML in the associated Javascript function.

Whenever I use the same JS, but replace the "select" with other HTML, it works perfectly fine. It is only < input type="button" /> and < button >  that do not work.

The problem appears in at least IE, Firefox, and Chrome. Chrome returns an "Unexpected Identifier" error.

The abbreviated code (NOT the original):

```
function newrow() {
    table = document.getElementById("Table");
    row = table.insertRow(1);
    cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = "<input id="Button" type="button" value="ClickHere" />";
};
```

I have tried replacing the HTML with formatted text ("< b > Text < / b >") and links, and both display correctly.

I have also created the object outside of the script, and this does work, but seems unnecessary:

```
<input id="Button" type="button" value="ClickHere" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function newrow() {
    table = document.getElementById("Table");
    button = document.getElementById("Button");
    row = table.insertRow(1);
    cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = button;
};
```

This works, but is ungainly and complicates any "getindex"s I use.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A select with a type="button"?

Comment: Are you aware of the double quotes issue in **"<select id="Button" type="button"**...?

Comment: Not counting the major syntax error in your posted code `cell.innerHTML = "<select id="Button" type="button" value="ClickHere" />";`, there is no 'type="select"` for buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An "Unexpected Identifier" error would be triggered by this line:

```
cell.innerHTML = "<input id="Button" type="button" value="ClickHere" />";
```

The problem is your quotes. The JavaScript interpreter is getting confused with the quotes used to represent strings in JavaScript and the quotes used inside HTML. You need to either escape the quotes within the string, or use single quotes for one of the purposes.

Single quotes would work:

```
cell.innerHTML = '<input id="Button" type="button" value="ClickHere" />';
```

Alternatively, escaping the quotes would work:

```
cell.innerHTML = "<input id=\"Button\" type=\"button\" value=\"ClickHere\" />";
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing the quotes did it!

(Sorry about the quick transcription. Should have been careful writing the code here. The actual code does have the correct tags. Don't know how "select" got into my head.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `<input type="button" />` not select maybe? The select element is for dropdown menus.

Comment: Wow! Wasn't expecting such fast responses!

This isn't a direct copy of the original code- I have "input" there. Poor transcription on my part....

Comment: You can still use the value tag in the input, I just got lazy typing. The value will be the words on the button. A button is what you are going for correct?

Comment: Correct!

I messed up transcribing my code to here- don't know why I put select instead.

Comment: The qutoes are the issue. Look at Stephen Booher's answer.